# Structural Search against return type of Annotated method in IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

As per the subject, I am trying to structurally search against all methods annotated with a specific annotation and with a specific return type.

To be clearer, if I have methods like the followings:

```
@MyAnnotation
public String myMethod1(){}
```

and

```
@MyAnnotation
public Integer myMethod2(){}
```

I would like to find a way to formulate a structural search in IntelliJ to find, e.g., "all methods annotated with `@MyAnnotation` and with return type of `String`" and such search would return only `myMethod1()`.

I am using IntelliJ 13 Ultimate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Structural Search, copy the existing template *Methods of the class*.
Modify it as follows:

```
class $Class$ { 
  @MyAnnotation
  $ReturnType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);
}
```

And edit the **$ReturnType$** variable to specify Text/Regexp:
`String`
(or optionally to be really sure 
`java\.lang\.String`)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Find in Path` with Regular expression.
`Text to find:` would be something like that:

```
@MyAnnotation\n\spublic.*myMethod1()
```

regards